# Disable mouse press on Tkinter Text Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-text

**Background**
I have created a tk.Text widget within a frame and used grid to place successfully within my tool. I use methods to run read commands and display the results within the tk.Text widget. I only want the tk.Text to display the results nothing else and this works as expected.

```
resultsbox = tk.Text(centerframe)
resultsbox.config(state='disabled', bd='10', height=38, width=92, bg='black', fg='green', font='fixedsys')
resultsbox.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
```

I use the following commands on each method to enable my write results and then disable the user from typing into the tk.Text widget:

Example

```
resultsbox.config(state='normal')
resultsbox.insert(tk.INSERT, RESULT1, 'standard', "\n\n")
resultsbox.config(state='disabled')
```

This again works as expected.

**Issue**
The problem i have is if a user clicks within the tk.Text widget even though it is disabled the next result that the tool writes to the widget will place it at the point where the user last clicked causing a very unreadable result.

Example
[This Screenshot shows if a user has clicked within the widget and then the next result is written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y10kl.png)

**Summary**
Is it possible to stop the user pressing within the tk.Text widget?

Comment: Try adding `resultsbox.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda e: "break")`.

Comment: Why are you writing the results to INSERT rather than to the end of the widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley i started learning Python in December and decided to choose a project to focus on. This Tkinter project has really grown but i am still missing bits like the .End which ultimately will now never be forgotten :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to disable your mouse keys. It is very simple. You just replace `tk.INSERT` with `tk.END`. This tells *where* to insert. Either at the marked position or at the end. Check out my example. I created 2 buttons, one with `tk.INSERT` and one with `tk.END`.

```
import tkinter as tk


def insert_END():
    RESULT1 = '---OUTPUT---'
    resultsbox.config(state='normal')
    resultsbox.insert(tk.END, RESULT1, 'standard', "\n\n")
    resultsbox.config(state='disabled')


def insert_INSERT():
    RESULT1 = '---OUTPUT---'
    resultsbox.config(state='normal')
    resultsbox.insert(tk.INSERT, RESULT1, 'standard', "\n\n")
    resultsbox.config(state='disabled')


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
frame1 = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=1)

resultsbox = tk.Text(frame1)
resultsbox.config(state='disabled', bd='10', height=38, width=92, bg='black', fg='green', font='fixedsys')
resultsbox.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1, sticky="e")

btn1 = tk.Button(master=frame1, text='END', command=insert_END)
btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30)

btn2 = tk.Button(master=frame1, text='INSERT', command=insert_INSERT)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is perfect, works just as i need it to :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The state 'disampled' is an editing property and means that the text cannot be modified. I do not know if that is linked with the cursor position issue you describe (as I get it).

If I understand it correctly the issue is that even when the textbox is disabled and you click in it, the position of the click is remembered and the next time you enable the textbox again it inserts the new text at the last position. If this is the issue, I would try to place the cursor at the end of the actual text (e.g. Text.insert(tk.END,...) before the disable command. When you change the status to 'enable' you can then add the new text to the end of the previous string. Alternatively I would try each time I enable the Text widget to check where the cursor is and move it to the end of the previous string.